# Where should font-family be defined for an entire page?

Tags: css, font-family

I'm going to define a font-family to be used for the entire page (unless specifically modified by a lower element/id/class), and I was wondering whether its better practice (or more common) to designate the font-family for the html tag or the body tag?

The property should automatically be inherited to all the content that I can think of regardless of I designated it in html or body, so I wonder if it even matters?  I noticed Google and Wikipedia both designate the font-family for BOTH the html and body elements, so I'm curious as to what the advantages of defining font-family for either/both of the elements.

If you could point out cases in which either tag would be preferable, that'd be excellent.

Comment: I'd use it for the `body` element as it makes more sense than setting it up for the `html` element. I doubt if setting it for `html` element matters as all elements will inherit attribute value from `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more common to set font properties on the `body` element than on the `html` element. Normally, it doesn’t really matter.

Setting them on the `html` element lets any other style sheet override your font settings by just setting their font settings on `body`. This might sometimes be desirable.

It would also matter in the rare cases where you make some elements in the `head` part visible, with CSS, against their default setting of `display: none`.

Comment: _“Setting them on the `html` element lets any other style sheet override your font settings by just setting their font settings on `body`.”_ – they can do that anyway – with a rule of the same specificity if the are embedded later, or with one with a higher one should they be embedded before … so I’d say that’s not really a valid argument here.

Comment: @CBroe, it wasn’t really an argument, just a point. And I think it is valid: doing so lets any style sheet override your settings even if it would lose to your settings on `body`, e.g. due to being a user style sheet.